Singular Matrix error while adding filter capacitor across the load in 3 phase diode based rectifier
I am trying to simulate a simple 3 phase diode based rectifier circuit in LT Spice. By using a filter capacitor across the load I am getting a singular Matrix error as shown in the picture. The error log points towards node n001( the one above diode D1). Not sure what it suggests.The singular Matrix error occuring after connecting a filter capacitor across the load
It worked fine when I used the existing diode models in  lt spice. This started when I defined a custom diode as shown in the picture.

Try adding some ESR in series with the capacitor. Sometimes components that are "too ideal" can cause problems with the MNA matrix.

@JohnD it worked fine when I used the existing diode models in the lt spice. This started when I defined a custom diode. Nevertheless I'll try what you suggested.

Which of those nodes is n001?

Add some series resistance to C1. Strangely, moving the GND connection to the capacitor's negative end fixes the problem, just tried.

Or another thing to try might be to put a very high value resistor e.g. 10 Meg from the capacitor negative to the existing ground.

it worked fine when I used the existing diode models in the lt spice. This started when I defined a custom diode. you didn't specify a custom diode. It's still the ideal diode model and you defined some maximum values which normally don't have any effect on electrical behaviour.

@Justme the one above diode D1

@RohatKılıç You mean I need to add some stray resistance and inductances along with those?

@PankitShah it's always better to define the parasitic components for a more realistic simulation. For your case, defining the ESR for the capacitor seems enough. For the inductor, the ESR is 1 milliohm by default but it can be zero for the capacitor. So, do a right click on the capacitor, open the properties window and put something like 10m into the ESR field.

Note that a so "great" capacitor (4700 uF) should not be used alone. It should be better to use an inductor between the + of the bridge and the load (including the C1 capacitor)

Without this inductor, the charge current could be something like 50 kA. Check always all (voltages, currents, powers in all components).

When you "defined" a custom diode, does that diode behave like any real diode would? What you describe is exactly how Spice would behave if the diodes were ideal.

Add Rs=1 to your diode parameters. And change Vrev to BV.

@PankitShah I talk about behavioral diodes in LTspice here. Please carefully consider your designed mode for the behavioral diode. If you specify the diode well (read what I wrote) then the simulation will run a lot better. Also, there's no need for "jumpers" in your schematic. They actually add a voltage source each time you place one on the schematic. And it just makes the schematic that much harder to simulate.

If you carefully read the help documentation in LTspice, on the topic of diode models, you will see that it says "There are two types of diodes available."
One of them is the usual sophisticated version of the Shockley Diode model. That's the one where you specify things like the emission coefficient and the saturation current. But apparently you don't intend to use that one.
The remaining one is a "region-wise linear model" which basically means it is a piece-wise model. And while these are "light-weight" models, they are also very, very annoying for simulation:

Note the sharp corners? You don't want that!! Sharp corners may drive simulation insane! So you must specify the tanh parameter epsilon to smooth over the curves.
Here's an example using epsilon values to round the corners:

Also, while neither of the above two pictures show it (because the voltage sweep doesn't go far enough), the values for ILimit and RevILimit do affect the model behavior:

The above two images include how the epsilon parameter rounds over the corners. That's good. You want that.
But what you don't want is the ILimit parameter. It will cause trouble here. And I think you should also not specify the RevILimit parameter. Don't do either. This keeps things simpler for the simulator. If you add them it may cause simulation trouble here. So just avoid them.
I'd recommend modifying the model seen below to fit your needs:

